# Why does 'sealed' affect the implementation of IDisposable?

Tags: .net, .net-2.0, idisposable, sealed

After reading the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898828/c-sharp-finalize-dispose-pattern), I decided to mark my class as sealed in order to simplify the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) implementation.  Why does sealed affect the implementation of IDisposable (e.g. `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` does not need to be called)?  Please explain what is happening.  I need to be able to explain to a fellow developer why I made the class sealed.

Comment: If you didn't understand what you were doing, then why did you do it?

Answer (score 2):

If a class which implements `IDisposable` is not sealed, it is likely that a derived class will need to do something in response to `Dispose`, but the base-class actions for `Dispose` should be performed as well.  If the class exposes a public `Dispose` member which will always be synonymous with `IDisposable.Dispose`, the necessary semantics could be achieved in C# by simply using implicit interface implementation with a public virtual `Dispose` method.

There are two problems with that approach:

1. It would require derived classes use a different method in cases where the parent exposes a public `Dispose` method, than in cases where it does not; things could get very muddy if a class which doesn't expose a public `Dispose` method is inherited by an unsealed class which does.

   Some base disposal code should run before the derived-class disposal code (e.g. the code that suppresses repeated `Dispose` attempts), and some should run after (e.g. `GC.SuppressFinalize()`).  The only way to achieve that is to have a non-virtual wrapper call a protected virtual function.  Note, btw, that Microsoft's wrapper doesn't properly suppress repeated-`Dispose`, but the wrapper is the only good place for such suppression code.

Note that Microsoft seems to have intended its `Dispose` pattern to be used in the cases where a base class does not override `Finalize`, but a derived class uses `Finalize` for cleanup.  While that may have been the intent, it is not a good pattern for that purpose.  With very few exceptions, the only classes which should only override `Finalize` for cleanup are those which derive from trivial classes like `Object`.  If a class implements `IDisposable` but does not override `Finalize`, the only purpose for which a derived class should override `Finalize` is to sound an alarm if `Finalize` ever gets called, and even that usage is debatable (a better pattern would be:

```
class whatever:IDisposable
{
  IDisposable DisposedStatusObject;
  // Generate a static dummy object instance we can use as a sentinel value
  // It needs to be `IDisposable`, but shouldn't actually hold any resources.

  static IDisposable DisposedStatusDisposed = new List<int>().GetEnumerator();

  public bool Disposed {get {return (DisposedStatusObject == DisposedStatusDisposed);} }

  whatever()
  {
    DisposedStatusObject = new DisposalAlarm(); // First thing in constructor
  }
  void Dispose()
  {
    IDisposable prevStatus;
    prevStatus = Interlocked.Exchange(DisposedStatus, DisposedStatusDisposed);
    if (prevStatus != DisposedStatusDisposed)
    {
      Dispose(true);
      prevStatus.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

The `DisposalAlarm()` class is assumed to be a class with an overridden `Finalize()` method which sounds an alarm if that `Finalize()` method gets called without its `Dispose()` method being called first.  The `Dispose` method for `whatever` will ensure that, if the derived-class method returns properly, the alarm will get cancelled.  Note that if an instance of `whatever` has an unsuppressed finalizer, everything to which `whatever` holds a direct or indirect reference will have to be kept around until that finalizer has either run or been suppressed.  By contrast, the addition of a `DisposalAlarm` object does not extend the lifetime of anything in `whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

Making a class `sealed` means that there can be no classes derived from it. That means that the implementation of `IDisposable` doesn't need to take into account the behavior (or misbehavior) of derived classes.

Comment: Yes I understand the sealed keyword. Please explain why I do not need to call GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

Comment: I don't know why not. You also didn't ask this in your question. If you want to know the answer about `GC.SuppressFinalize`, then you should edit your question to include that.

Comment: Thought my question specifically asked about the difference in implementation, isn't GC.SuppressFinalize a difference?

Comment: Can you point to the documentation in which you read that you do not need to call `GC.SupressFinalize` if you seal the class?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - In addition to the link in the question?

Comment: The documentation states `Leave out the finalizer altogether if this class doesn't own unmanaged resources itself` and the notes in the stackoverflow post you linked states `you should only implement a finalizer if you have actual unmanaged resources to dispose.` None of them mention this being related to sealing a class. they are referring to unmanaged resources. So where do you get it from that sealing a class has to do with calling the finalizer?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl - I see what you mean.

Comment: Ah I see, because he didn't implement it you assumed it is because you do not have to. Here is a post where a sealed class implements it and uses unmanaged resources (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418970/implementing-idisposable-on-a-sealed-class) I think the post you linked was only giving an example. In general, as far as I know finalization only matters when referring to unmanaged resources.

Comment: 白ジェームス: `GC.SuppressFinalize` should generally be called on classes which override `Finalize`, after disposal is complete. If a sealed class overrides `Finalize`, it should call `GC.SuppressFinalize`. Likewise if a class isn't sealed and a derived class overrides `Finalize`. Note that only the non-virtual `Dispose` wrapper knows when disposal is really complete, so `GC.SuppressFinalize` must be called from the base.  Note also that it's cheaper for the base class to unconditionally call `GC.SuppressFinalize` than it would be to only call it when a derived class overrides `Finalize`.

Answer (score 1):

A sealed class is not intended to be used as a base class, while an unsealed class is. Hence lies the distinction: an unsealed class needs to provide a way for its derived classes to implement `Dispose()` of their own, while a sealed class is free of this responsibility, because it cannot be extended.